# Interface to configure OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I want to import a OpenVPN-Config or create a new one. I don't want to write a configuration file manually. Is there a configurator application that can help me?

Comment: I'm not sure this is very elementary-specific, and might be better off on the Unix or Ubuntu stackexchanges.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install OpenVPN and the Configuration Interface.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Then you can import or create new Configurations like for PPTP.

[Source](http://eos-snippets.blogspot.de/2013/10/vpnbook-free-vpn.html)

Comment: i would like to have an answer with screenshots that shows how to import a configuration. maybe i find some time or someone else...